# Forcing UnityContainer to create instance on specific thread

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to find a way to make my UnityContainer create instances that inherit from DispatcherObject on the UI thread.  Basically this is what I want:

```
if (objectType is DispatcherObject)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        // DO BUILDUP HERE
    );
}
else
{
    // DO BUILDUP HERE
}
```

Looking at the Unity source code I can't find a good way to do this.  My best option so far is to register a static factory for every instance I want to push to the UI thread but I would like all DispatcherObject derived classes to be created on the UI thread.